# Wait till all multiple asynchronous ajax call are completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Hello I have multiple ajax call, what I wanted to do is to fire all of them asynchronously then wait till all of them are finished before processing the returned data. I tried using $.when but to no avail. Here is my code:

```
//form_identifier_list is my flag to get the multiple forms in my html page
function test(form_identifier_list){
    var deffereds = [];

    $.each(form_identifier_list, function(key,value){
        var this_form = $(this).parents('.ajaxed_form');
        deffereds.push( $.post($(this_form).attr("action"), $(this_form).serializeForm()) );
    });

    $.when.apply($, deffereds).done(function(){
        //how to output response obj?? i tried console.log(data) to no avail
    }).fail(function(){

    }).always(function(){

    });
}
```

I also noticed my ajax requests do not have reponse (which i verified on my browser).

Is there a way to make multiple ajax calls fire asynchronously and then wait till all of them are finished then access the data?

Thanks

Comment: your code looks OK with the possible exception of your use of `.always()` on a promise chain.  You need to describe how the code fails, and/or any errors produced.

Comment: `I also noticed my ajax requests do not have reponse` - If your ajax requests have no response - then what are you expecting to log in your done function?

Comment: when I call my $.post multiple times the last one will have response. I'll put my code for your reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the jquery page on [when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), there is a section that says:

> In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to
>   jQuery.when(), the method returns the Promise from a new "master"
>   Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds
>   it has been passed.

Also there is this on the [ajax page](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the
>   Promise interface

So we can just assign the return value of the `ajax` to a variable and pass those variables into the `.when`.

To expand slightly on the example given on the `.when` page and integrate any number of ajax calls, you can do something like this:

```
var ajaxes = [];
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    ajaxes.push($.ajax('a.php', {data: {t: i}}));
}
$.when.apply($, ajaxes)
    .done(function(){
        for(var i=0;i<arguments.length; i++) {
            $('#output').append(arguments[i] + "<br>");
        };
    });
```

If you have a known number of ajax calls, it gets a little simpler...you can do something more like this:

```
var a1 = $.ajax(...);
var a2 = $.ajax(...);
var a3 = $.ajax(...);
$.when(a1,a2,a3).done(function(o1, o2, o3) {
  $('#output').append(o1).append(o2).append(o3);
});
```

The first example is basically doing the same thing.

Comment: Hello mr. david so I should not use $.post when consolidating my ajax requests?

Comment: I don't see any content here - the OP already knows how to use   `$.when.apply`.  His problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use [post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), there is a section on that page which also says 1.5+ implements the Promise interface.

Comment: @Alnitak is right, I'm sorry to recount so much of what you did. I think the main problem is that you aren't passing in jQuery as your "this" object when you do your `.apply`. I suspect this is important, since you are chaining.

Comment: Ye, he is - `$.when.apply($, ...)`, and in any event jQuery doesn't actually care.  The problem is with the failed responses from `$.ajax()`.

Comment: @Alnitak he has edited his post...original post said `$.when.apply(this, ...)`. You may be right, I haven't looked at the source for `$.when`, and don't know if it relies on `this` being jQuery.

Comment: I have, and it doesn't ;)  It's still a good idea to use `$`, though.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to asynchronously call on several JavaScript functions (e.g. Ajax functions), wait for each of the functions to finish and then continue (e.g. access data) using setInterval.

Consider three JavaScript functions (i=0,1,2). Each function performs the same number of operations (10). After the system starts (T_0), each of the functions has a beginning (T_(3i+2)  or〖 T〗_2,〖 T〗_5  and〖 T〗*8), an operation to perform ten times (T*(3i+3)  or〖 T〗_3, 〖 T〗_6  and〖 T〗*9), and an ending (T*(3i+4)  or〖 T〗_4, 〖 T〗_7  and〖 T〗_10). When the functions are ready to begin, the functions may start in any order. Each function performs its operations ten times. When every function has finished performing its operation, the system continues (T_1) and the three functions may be performed again.

Figure 1: A Petri Net Model for Synchronizing Three Function Calls
[image: A Petri Net Model for Synchronizing Three Function Calls]

The function that setInterval executes does the following:

1. Selects an (ajax) function to execute, and executes the function. For example each of T_3, T_6 and〖 T〗_9  in Figure 1 may represent a function call for an (ajax) function that is called ten times.
2. If every (ajax) function has finished its task then the function continues and clears the interval object.

Consider the following sample code snippet:

```js
var s1=false, s2=false, s3=false;
// a1 (an Ajax function) sets s1 to true if it is finished
function a1() { …}
// a2 (an Ajax function) sets s2 to true if it is finished 
function a2() {…}
// a3 (an Ajax function) sets s3 to true if it is finished
function a3() {…}
// fcon is the function to execute when a1, a2 and a3 has finished.
function fcon() {…}
function myFunction() {
  var af = [], i;
  If (s1) af[af.length] = 1;
  If (s2) af[af.length] = 2;
  If (s3) af[af.length] = 3;
  If (af.length==0) {
    fcon();
    clearInterval(ai);
    ai = undefined;
  } else {
    i = Math.round( (af.length-1)*Math.random());
    switch(af[i]) {
      case 1:
        a1(); break;
      case 2:
        a2(); break;
      case 3:
        a3(); break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
var ai = setInterval(“myFunction()”, 1000);
```

[This answer has a [PDF version](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/GouqM1461659532.pdf) whose figure is dynamic and interactive.]

Answer (score -4):

I want to suggest you something dirty (:

```
var counter=0;
$.ajax(success:function(){counter++})
$.ajax(success:function(){counter++})
$.ajax(success:function(){counter++})
$.ajax(success:function(){counter++})
$.ajax(success:function(){counter++})

var interval = setInterval(function(){
 If(counter===5){
   // fire event to elaborate data
   // clear interval
 }
})
```

Comment: I want to _very_ strongly suggest you don't.

Comment: doing things like `++` with async operations is a recipe for disaster. This is often not thread safe, and you can end up losing an increment.

Comment: @David784 well, JS doesn't actually have threads, so in JS this is fine, but in modern JS this would be utterly horrible code.