# Remove items from JSON object dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to delete certain items from a JSON object under certain conditions.

I am making two Ajax requests, one to get items from an API endpoint and save the JSON object in a variable called `items`. I'm using the `ID` of each item to make a subsequent API request.

If the second API returns a non-empty object, delete the specific item from my JSON Object. Then render the items (meaning only display items that are yet to be approved).

### API Request 1

```
var items;

function fetchItems() {
  $.ajax({
    url: urlOne,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      items = data.d.results;
      getPendingItems();
    },
  });
}
```

### API Request 2

```
function getPendingItems() {
  for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $.ajax({
      url: urlTwo + items[i].Id,
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(data.d.results)) {
          //
        } else {
          removeItems(i);
        }
      },
    })
  }
}

function removeItems(key) {
  delete items[key];
}
```

### My Data Structure

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Item_name": "test1"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Item_name": "test2"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Item_name": "test3"
    },
]
```

However, the items are not being deleted from my JSON object. I end up rendering all the items

Comment: use `async:false` in `ajax` call.

Comment: pass items as getPendingItems() param

Comment: @manikantgautam no, never do that. Ever. It's incredibly bad practice.

Comment: @gerry note that while this can be done, it's really not a good idea to make an AJAX request then N more AJAX requests to check each item which was returned in the first one. It will not scale, and will cause performance issues on your server. Instead, return *all* required data in a single request. Even if this returns a larger response, it will still scale better than what you have now. It also avoids the problem of having to maintain the object, as whatever you receive from the first call is up to date.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am using MS Sharepoint Rest API's and there is no way to filter data from different tables (lists). The only way is to make multiple calls

Comment: Ouch, Sharepoint. Ok, best of luck.

Comment: How do you determine the items are not "deleted"? Add a `console.log(i, items)` before and after the call to `removeItems(i);`; the `i`th element should become `undefined`. Perhaps your problem is that you "render" items too early - in that case see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36705604/1026